# ColdFusion: trying to create dynamic downloadable PDF, but not create a file?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I haven't been able to find an answer to this ColdFusion/PDF question so here goes:

I already have a back-end that creates dynamic PDFs using `CFDOCUMENT`. The user has to submit payment first via authorize.net, then once the payment is processed, they click a link to download a dynamic PDF we create.

The PDF is saved in a file on our server. The link the user clicks to download it calls `CFHEADER` and `CFCONTENT` which points to the PDF location on the server and it downloads for them.

However, I don't want to store the PDFs on the server anymore if I don't have to. I'd like them to be able to click the link to download, then have the PDF be generated dynamically, be available for download, **but not saved on the server**.

Is this possible? Or do you have to create a file for them first if they want to download a dynamically created PDF?

Comment: I do exactly this using `cfhtmltopdf`

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? As @TRose said, you could try cfhtmltopdf, but this is only available since CF11: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhtmltopdf.html

Comment: I'm using version 2016, so this should work. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I do it on a test page I have in version 9.

```
<cfdocument format="pdf">
Hello.  This is a very simple pdf file.
</cfdocument>
```

It is called by this anchor tag.

```
<a href="pdf_output.cfm" target="_blank">
Click here to open new tab/window with pdf content that is generated at runtime.
</a>
```

Comment: I tried this which does open up a PDF in the browser, but doesn't start an automatic download. I tried adding CFHEADER and CFCONTENT to pdf_output.cfm, but it didn't trigger a download. Hmm...

Comment: Based on the link from @Sander in the comment to your question, you might find the same behaviour with cfhtmltopdf.

Comment: It looks like cfhtmltopdf doesn't have some of the section processing I use which cfdocument has. I think I'm going to use this example and just let the user know they have to right-click/save as to download the pdf from their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your link can send them to a page with something like this, where `#thePDF#` contains a binary object created from [`<cfdocument name="thePDF" ...>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdocument.html):

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=mypdf.pdf"/>
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#thePDF#" />
```

Comment: You would have to create a file first with this method, correct?