# How to set file name displayed in "Save As..." dialog for dynamic PDF displayed in iframe

Tags: pdf, iframe, coldfusion

I am generating a pdf dynamically in ColdFusion, so that there are no actual PDF's on our server. Every time the user hits 'download' it dynamically creates a PDF by opening another browser window, using an `<iframe>` within the window where the pdf is created.

However, I'm not sure how to change the actual filename displayed when the user clicks "Save As..". Currently, the file name displayed is the name as the .cfm file used to generate the pdf, e.g. `my_pdf_generated.pdf`. Ideally I'd like the file to have a date in the name, e.g. `my_pdf_generated_040918.pdf`, but I can't seem to find how to do that.

This is the code that runs in the separate browser window when the user clicks 'Download pdf'.

```
<div class="title">
  Loading your pdf. Your document may take a few moments to 
  load. Once it's loaded, you can save it to your device.</div>
  <cfflush>
  <iframe src="property_valuation.cfm?valco=<cfoutput>#URL.ValCo#</cfoutput>" 
      width="100%" height="100%" >
   </iframe>
</div>
```

*property_valuation.cfm:*

```
... other code ...
<cfdocument format="pdf"  margintop="1.0" marginbottom=".75" >
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   ... generate pdf content here ...
</body>
</html>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the relevant code (code generating pdf for download, ... property_valuation.cfm). Are you using `<cfheader>` as suggested in [this older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066873/coldfusion-trying-to-create-dynamic-downloadable-pdf-but-not-create-a-file)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I posted the working code above.

Comment: What's the purpose of the iframe?

Comment: @TassTimes - Since S.O. is a Q&A site you should post the non-working code in the "question", and the working code as a separate "answer". Also, the only code in `property_valuation.cfm` that's really relevant to this specific issue is the `<cfdocument>` tags. The rest can be removed.

Comment: @TassTimes - post your working code as the answer and accept it

Comment: @DanBracuk, the iframe is so we can display a text banner over the slooow-loading pdf iframe to the user for instructions on downloading the pdf and to please be patient while their pdf loads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer:

I was missing a CFHEADER statement that allows the filename parameter which will be used when the user does right-click, "Save as...". You can also set a variable to the date and time and include that variable as part of the filename to make it unique.

*property_valuation.cfm:*

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="inline; filename=mypdf.pdf"/>
```

Comment: It would help others to better understand the solution if A) only the relevant code was included, which is just 2 lines (cfheader + cfdocument) and b) also included a brief explanation of *why* it worked. (I would edit it myself, but it would surely be rejected as "too drastic" ;-)

Comment: All set per your suggestion.

Comment: Looks great, thanks! Much easier for others to follow.